# Avg Salaries under current managers

Tags: mysql

I have this table: Employee

| emp_id | emp_name | salary | manager_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | emp_1 | 5000 | 7 |
| 2 | emp_2 | 3600 | 6 |
| 3 | emp_3 | 2500 | 7 |
| 4 | emp_4 | 4600 | 6 |
| 5 | emp_5 | 9000 | NULL |
| 6 | emp_6 | 7500 | 5 |
| 7 | emp_7 | 2300 | 6 |

I want to get the Average salary for the employees under manager

Here is an example of the result I want:

| emp_id | emp_name | AVG_Salary |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | emp_5 | 7500 |
| 6 | emp_6 | 3500 //which is (3600 + 4600 + 2300) / 3; |
| 7 | emp_7 | 3750 //which is (5000+ 2500) / 2; |

Can you please tell me how to figure out what I need to get the query please.

Comment: Go on. Try something, and see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: please try the given solution and try to figure it or modify it based on your requirements, please try it too and feel free to ask me for any thing you don't understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Here is the solution:**

```
SELECT e2.emp_id AS "Manager_ID", e2.emp_name AS "Manager_Name", AVG(e1.salary) AS "AVG" 
FROM Employee e1,
            Employee e2
WHERE e1.manager_id = e2.emp_id
GROUP BY e2.emp_id, e2.emp_name 
ORDER BY e2.emp_id;
```

**Description:**
We want to join on the same table in this problem and we want to select the managers who are (5-6-7) in this case (e2) and the case is that e1 manager id is what we want, and to get the avg we use AVG function on the employees salaries (e1) in this case and we use GROUP BY to collect the avg and ORDER BY to order it.